# Issue with Image Cropper in Fabric.js - Overlapping Boundaries at Non-Zero Degrees Rotation

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I have been working on a custom image cropper using Fabric.js, where I extended the image object to implement the functionality. The cropper works perfectly when the image rotation angle is zero degrees. However, when I rotate the image to any non-zero degree, the cropper boundaries and the image overlap, causing unwanted results.

Here's a brief overview of the setup:

I created a custom class that extends the Fabric.js image object to handle cropping functionality.
Cropping works flawlessly at zero degrees rotation.
The issue arises when I apply rotation to the image (non-zero degrees) and try to crop it.
I suspect the problem lies in the way I handle coordinate transformations during the rotation process, but I am unable to pinpoint the exact cause.

To clarify, I want the cropping boundaries to respect the rotated image's dimensions and not overlap with the image itself. I have tried several approaches, including adjusting the boundary calculations based on the image's rotation, but without success.

I am seeking guidance on how to properly restrict the cropping boundaries when the image is rotated. Any insights, suggestions, or code examples would be highly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and expertise. If you need any further information or code snippets to understand the issue better, please let me know, and I'll be happy to provide them.

when the cropper gets outside the image, it should be restricted:
[image]

I have tried to restrict the boundings when the angle is zero degrees, because thats easier you only have to deal with the left, top .